# Restrict users from saving on their Desktop and saving on a specific folder

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, user-permissions, desktop

### Restrict users from saving on their Desktop and saving on a specific folder

I want to restrict my users to save files on their desktop and on a specific folder
like

**(C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Desktop Files)**

I searched the Internet a lot and there's a way to disable desktop but I want to save desktop files in a specific folder called "Desktop Files"

Is it possible to achieve that using Group Policy or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for your needs. Follow below steps:

**Step-1**. Create new "Group Policy Object"

**Step-2**.
[image]

**Step-3**.

[image]

**Step-4**.

[image]

**Step-5**.

[image]

**Step-6**.
After that, you can give your permissions as you want

Comment: Plz Upvote my question